# Ошибки в коде c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, http-status-code-404

Я писал код по видеоуроку некого иностранного кодера, код написан в Visual Studio обновлённой до последней версии, в своём проекте я использовал SDL 2.28.
Та самая часть кода, связанная с ошибками (изображение ниже):

Vector2D.h

```
#include <iostream>

class Vector2D {
public:
    float x, y;

    Vector2D(float x, float y);
    Vector2D();

    Vector2D& Add(const Vector2D& vec);
    Vector2D& Subtract(const Vector2D& vec);
    Vector2D& Multiply(const Vector2D& vec);
    Vector2D& Divide(const Vector2D& vec);

    friend Vector2D& operator+(Vector2D& vec1, const Vector2D& vec2);
    friend Vector2D& operator-(Vector2D& vec1, const Vector2D& vec2);
    friend Vector2D& operator*(Vector2D& vec1, const Vector2D& vec2);
    friend Vector2D& operator/(Vector2D& vec1, const Vector2D& vec2);

    Vector2D& operator+=(const Vector2D& vec);
    Vector2D& operator-=(const Vector2D& vec);
    Vector2D& operator*=(const Vector2D& vec);
    Vector2D& operator/=(const Vector2D& vec);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Vector2D& vec);
};
```

Vector2D.cpp

```
#include "Vector2D.h"

Vector2D::Vector2D() {
    x = 0.0f;
    y = 0.0f;
}

Vector2D::Vector2D(float x, float y) {
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}

Vector2D& Vector2D::Add(const Vector2D& vec) {
    this->x += vec.x;
    this->y += vec.y;

    return *this;
}

Vector2D& Vector2D::Subtract(const Vector2D& vec) {
    this->x -= vec.x;
    this->y -= vec.y;

    return *this;
}

Vector2D& Vector2D::Multiply(const Vector2D& vec) {
    this->x *= vec.x;
    this->y *= vec.y;

    return *this;
}

Vector2D& Vector2D::Divide(const Vector2D& vec) {
    this->x /= vec.x;
    this->y /= vec.y;

    return *this;
}

Vector2D& operator+(Vector2D& vec1, const Vector2D& vec2) {
    return vec1.Add(vec2);
}

Vector2D& operator-(Vector2D& vec1, const Vector2D& vec2) {
    return vec1.Subtract(vec2);
}

Vector2D& operator*(Vector2D& vec1, const Vector2D& vec2) {
    return vec1.Multiply(vec2);
}

Vector2D& operator/(Vector2D& vec1, const Vector2D& vec2) {
    return vec1.Divide(vec2);
}

Vector2D& Vector2D::operator+=(const Vector2D& vec) {
    return this->Add(vec);
}

Vector2D& Vector2D::operator-=(const Vector2D& vec) {
    return this->Subtract(vec);
}

Vector2D& Vector2D::operator*=(const Vector2D& vec) {
    return this->Multiply(vec);
}

Vector2D& Vector2D::operator/=(const Vector2D& vec) {
    return this->Divide(vec);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Vector2D& vec) {
    stream << '(' << vec.x << ", " << vec.y << ')';
    return stream;
}
```

TransformComponent.h

```
#include "Vector2D.h"

class TransformComponent {

public:
    
    Vector2D position;

    TransformComponent() {
        position.x = 0.0f;
        position.y = 0.0f;
    }

    TransformComponent(float x, float y) {
        position.x = x;
        position.y = y;
    }
};
```

В коде ниже есть включение "Game.h", в одном из классов которого находится статическое определение поля renderer (чтобы потом вопросов не было).

TextureManager.h

```
#include "Game.h"

class TextureManager {
public:
    static SDL_Texture* LoadTexture(const char* file);
    static void Draw(SDL_Texture* tex, SDL_Rect* src, SDL_Rect* dest);
};
```

TextureManager.cpp

```
#include "TextureManager.h"

SDL_Texture* TextureManager::LoadTexture(const char* texture)
{
    SDL_Surface* tmpSurface = IMG_Load(texture);
    SDL_Texture* tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(Game::renderer, tmpSurface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(tmpSurface);

    return tex;
}

void TextureManager::Draw(SDL_Texture* tex, SDL_Rect* src, SDL_Rect* dest) {
    dest->h = src->h * 2;
    dest->w = src->w * 2;

    SDL_RenderCopy(Game::renderer, tex, src, dest);
}
```

Выдаваемые ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я просто молю вас помогите мне разобраться в чём ошибки, потому что я здесь ничего неправильного не вижу, видимо я слеп.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Я изменил код. Теперь точь в точь как в оригинале.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема здесь:

```
class TextureManager {
public:
    SDL_Texture* TextureManager::LoadTexture(const char* texture) 
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...
```

То, что это метод класса нужно указывать, когда он не внутри определения класса.

Например:

```
class A {
public:
   void methodA() {} // этот метод определен внутри класса, A:: не используется
   void methodB();
};

void A::methodB() // a этот метод снаружи, поэтому нужно указывать A::
{
}
```

Видите разницу? Вот так:

```
class A {
public:
   void A::methodA() {}
};
```

писать нельзя. С классом `Vector2D` таже история.

Comment: Упс я случайно не то написал. Дело в том, чтобы сэкономить немного места, я скопировал код из .cpp файла и вставил его в заголовок и забыл убрать эту штуку, которую вы указали. На самом деле у меня этого нет, но ошибки всё равно выдаёт. Беспонятия в чём проблема.

Comment: Я изменил код. Теперь точь в точь как в оригинале.